# MySql Exception by Selecting Auto_Increment Values C#

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I want to get the username and userid, but when i executing the command
I get the Exception:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: startIndex"

The Database has the Items: UserID(AutoIncrement Int(9)(PK)) and UserName(Varchar(20))

**Code:**

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(DBConnection.ConnectionString))
{
connection.Open();
MySqlCommand getUser = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM User Where UserID = '42'", connection);
MySqlDataReader reader = getUser.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.HasRows){
```

> The Exception is thrown at "ExecuteReader".

**Queue**

"Select* From User Where UserID ='42'" is Executing without any trouble on the Server.

**My Question is:**

Why did I get an Index out of Range Exception ?

**Edit:**

I also tried only the query

> SELECT * FROM User Where `User`

But I get the same exception.

I can insert into the Table and I can get the Last insert ID but when I try to every Database with Select * From XY I get the same Exception. All the Tables are with innobDB and the all have at least 1 primary or foreign key.

**Edit2:**

If I only select the UserName the Query is working:

***Select UserName From User***

But when I try to get the UserID

***Select UserID From User***

I get the Exception:

> {"Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length."}    System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}

Comment: try defining the commandtype

Comment: nope i tried the types "text" and "tabledirect" without result

Comment: Did you try specifying columns _explicitly_ in the query?

Comment: Tried it now without success same Exception

Comment: The return is a single row is this nessesary ?

Comment: That shouldn't cause exception to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Try 42 without the quotes

```
"SELECT * FROM User Where UserID = 42"
```

Comment: Also without any success

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this edit of your code can help you.

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(DBConnection.ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    MySqlCommand getUser = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `User` WHERE `User`.`UserID` = 42", connection);
    MySqlDataReader reader = getUser.ExecuteReader();

    //rest of your code
}
```

I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

As a wise error spotting procedure I suggest to check if the error is located at sql level.

Try to get rid of the where clause simply  executing a plain query

```
SELECT * FROM `User`
```

Do you notice some change?

Comment: But I'm convinced the error lays outside the code you posted.

Comment: I tried but i get the same error I deleted the if statement and get directly to the connection.close() but the exception is at the execute method I can insert without any problems and i can get the last insert id

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but ExecuteReader create a generator. Any exception happening during results loop should popup at reader level. Use while(reader.read()) {} with ... Nothing inside. Do you get the error again?

Comment: The Exception is also thrown at ExecuteNonQuery()  the Exception is always thrown at the execution.